# What technology to use for communication in networks?

Tags: networking, rpc, zeromq

What technology is better to get communication server-to-server and between server-client? ZeroMQ, directly RPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you read a few resource on both the technologies.

There is no "one" better technologies but one of them may be more suitable to your needs.

Read on:

- [The excellent ZMQ guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall)
- [One of the early great introduction](http://nichol.as/zeromq-an-introduction)
- [MY shameless plug on my mini tutorial](http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

I am under impression that you already use RPC and are well aware of other technologies like HTTP based communication.